# Weird problems with variables and multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, loops, if-statement

I have a program with multiple threads. 
In my main thread I examine in a permanent loop whether a global variable has the value 1.
This variable I set during the runtime in the other thread with a Mutex locked on it to 1.
So the if condition should be true in the main thread. But it doesn't work... But if i put a printf before the if condition it works. This is so weird I have no idea whats wrong. Thanks

The code:

```
while(1) 
{
    printf("\n");
    if(logging_active == 1) {
        //check filesize every 30s. If logfile size over 1MB (1.000.000) send file
        if((timestamp_realtime_sec() - last_time) >= ((logtime+1))) {
            printf("check filesize...\n");
            if(fileSize("log") > 100000) {
                logfileHandler("log");
            }
            last_time = timestamp_realtime_sec();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
check filesize ...
```

Without the printf it's output nothing.

**Solution for me:**
changing the variable declaration from `int logging_active` to `volatile int logging_active` solved the problem.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: yes, sorry i forgot it. i edit it.

Comment: I see no mutex in the reading code... A mutex doesn't really work if you don't use it in all places where the protected resource/variable is accessed.

Comment: I assume logging_active is your variable. But where is mutex?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck, if your read is atomic, you don't *really* need to lock the variable for reading.

Comment: @StoryTeller It would require that the write is atomic too which is by no means guaranteed. (The write might for instance be composed by 3 bitwise operations performed in sequence, and without the mutex lock the read could be done after 2 of those operations yielding a crappy value.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know you're updating the variable from another thread, so it may not be actually checking it every time.  Mark the variable as `volatile` and it should work as you expect.  This tells the compiler that it isn't allowed to omit loads from that variable--it really has to read it every time.

Comment: AKA, what `volatile` *really* means in a multi-threaded context.

Comment: AFAIK, if the variable is non-static global (which it pretty much has to be when used in several different source files), then `volatile` or not, the compiler will not optimize it away.

Comment: I doubt this is what happens because (1) OP claims **But if i put a printf before the if condition it works.** (2) I am not aware of any C compiler that requires `volatile` in order to work correctly in a multi-threaded context (i.e. optmizes away incorrectly).

Comment: @barakmanos: The compiler won't optimize the variable away, but it might optimize away repeated loads (if it doesn't "see" that there are intermediate stores).

Comment: @usr, the sentence you quoted is a hint that this *is* probably what happens. The compiler can't optimize away a read after a function call, since the call may have side-effects.

Comment: I doubt that any decent compiler would make this sort of assumption on a non-static global variable.

Comment: @barakmanos, And I doubt any compiler is precluded from single-threadedness assumptions (especially pre c11). Only examining assembly code will tell for sure.

Comment: @StoryTeller It depends on what that printf() does. Besides, a compiler can very well deduce whether or not a printf() call has any side-effect. Your claim and this answer assume some sort of buggy compiler that doesn't know that a global variable can be modified from multiple threads.

Comment: @usr, of course it depends on what it does. The compiler can't know, hence it doesn't assume. Different vendors ship different standard library implementations, and sometimes without source. How can syntax analysis conclude no side-effects if the function definition isn't present!? It's intractable! We don't "assume some sort of buggy claim", we just understand how optimizations can go wrong in multi-threaded environments, since compilers aren't omniscient.

Comment: Thank you  that worked! I would never have done that.

Comment: This answer is really bad advice. While this might have worked in this particular case for the OP, there is no guarantee at all that threads see a consistent value of a global variable. You should either use atomic variables for that (if you have a C11 compiler that supports this) or protect the shared variable with a mutex.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I know every time someone mentioned volatile it's tempting to say it's wrong, but in this case it really works.  A mutex isn't needed here (what exactly would it be protecting against?).

Comment: @JohnZwinck The write operation might be composed by 3 bitwise operations performed in sequence, and without a mutex lock the read could be done after 2 of those operations yielding a crappy value. It would of course be easy to replace that with a single operation (doing the intermediate steps in another variable), but you asked for an example...

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: The OP only sets the value `1`.  There cannot be "3 bitwise operations."

Comment: @JohnZwinck I was merely pointing out that using a mutex when writing is pointless if you don't use the same mutex when reading. He doesn't show that code, so it isn't clear *how* it arrives at the value 1. In this case a mutex shouldn't be needed at all, just as you say, because it is likely that the variable is a flag.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are locking mutex and updating logging_active in other thread. You should lock the same mutex and do the check in current thread.

```
pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
while(logging_active == 0) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex)
        sleep(SOME_TIME);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex)
    //Your code
}
```

But I recommend you to use [condition variables](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait).